# What does "hit margin" mean?

Tags: meaning, terminology

This is used in an economic context:

> We don't monetize ourselves properly,
>   so we don't **hit margins**.

Answer (score 2):

One of the meanings of *hit* is *to reach or attain (a specified level or amount)*; *profit margin* is *the amount by which revenue from sales exceeds costs in a business*.

> Prices are expected to hit a new low.
>   The new train cab hit 100 mph.

The sentence you reported can be rewritten as

> We don't monetize ourselves properly, so we don't reach high profit margins.

Comment: I think the implicit word is "expected," or that the word is referring to specific margins that were introduced earlier.

Comment: I take that _margins_ is referring to _profit margin_, which is _the amount by which revenue from sales exceeds costs in a business_.

Answer (score 1):

*Margins* are edges of a thing. In *finance*, a margin is "a sum deposited with a broker to cover the risk of loss on a transaction or account." There is no larger context to the sentence, but I would expect that the word *monetize* signifies that the term is being used in the financial sense. What it probably means is that the enterprise is worried that if it doesn't get enough capital going forward, the creditors are likely to call in the debt.

Answer (score 1):

**Margin** is the difference between what it **costs** a business to buy or produce something and what they **sell** for it.

So to hit margin simply means to profit.

Meaning of sentence:

> We don't make money enough to maker our sales more than our costs.

Answer (score 0):

"Margin" is synonymous with "profit" in this sentence. "Monetize" is basically converting a hard asset to a liquid (cash) asset.

Basically:

> "We don't turn our assets into cash
>   well, so we don't make the profits
>   that we have budgeted for ourselves."